# Azure Pack Service Bus - Windows Fabric Missing

Tags: windows, azure-service-fabric, azure-pack

Recieve this error when configuring service bus before joining it to WAPAdmin Portal.
How can i install Windows Fabric which should contain FabricHostSrv manually. I cannot find a standalone installer for this.

> [Error] [12/15/2017 10:05:47 AM]:
>   System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException: Service
>   FabricHostSvc was not found on computer '.'. --->
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Service FabricHostSvc was not found
>   on computer '.'. --->
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The
>   specified service does not exist as an installed service
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Answer (score 0):

Run this command from PS window:
WebpiCmd.exe /offline /products:WindowsFabric /Path:c:\temp\OfflineCache

More info: https://rakibism.wordpress.com/2015/11/09/sharepoint-2013-workflow-manager-configuration-error-service-fabrichostsvc-was-not-found-on-computer/